# Biblatex: Highlight single words in Title

Tags: biblatex

I have a rather weird specific challenge while writing a paper for university. They have a very specific way they want their bibliography and I figured that I don't really have a way around creating a custom biblatex.cfg and defining some drivers for myself.

Now I got everything what I needed so far except for the following requirement. If the name of a work of some other author is part of the title of, say a book, I am citing this particular title "in" the title should be italic.

To give an example, I have the following citation:

[image: Example citation]

Here the I have the title "Antropofagia, intertextualidade e carnavalização na tradução do texto literário para o cinema em Vidas Secas, Macunaı́ma e Auto da Compadecida"

Now the words "Vidas Secas", "Macunaı́ma" and "Auto da Compadecida"
are names of other works and therefore should be italic.

My first idea was to make a list of names/words which biblatex could scan for and whenever those words appear they should be made italic. 
Only problem is that I don't really have a clue so far, how to do that.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/why-is-thanks-inappropriate-at-the-end-of-a-question

Comment: This is a fairly standard requirement. Why not simply wrap the titles in `\emph{}` in your `.bib` file directly?

Comment: Wow, I was not aware that this was possible. I feel rather stupid now, that the solution was so easy. Anyways, thanks a lot. This solves all my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement that titles of other works mentioned in a title should be typeset differently is common one, since the words in the mentioned title are not part of the words in the title itself.  Such markup should generally be made part of your `.bib` file itself, since it is properly part of the semantics of the entry, in the same way that certain types of capitalization are maintained using braces.

So the solution is to edit the `.bib` entry itself using `\emph`. You should *not* use `\textit`, since you don't want to specify the formatting, only the semantics.

So your `.bib` entry would look something like this:

```
@url{Grossi2013,
    Author = {Grossi, Elvair},
    Title = {Antropofagia, intertextualidade e carnavaliza{\c c}{\~a}o na
    tradu{\c c}{\~a}o do texto liter{\'a}rio para o cinema em 
    \emph{Vidas Secas}, \emph{Macuna{\'\i}ma} e \emph{Auto da Compadecida}},
    Urldate = {2013}}
```